# get most shipment day

Tags: sql-server

Write a query to get the day of the week that most shipments are sent on. For example we send most our shipments on Fridays.

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(DW, [ShipDate]) AS 'Day', 
    COUNT(*) AS 'Number of shipments/per day'
FROM   
    [Purchasing].[PurchaseOrderHeader]
WHERE  
    [ShipDate] IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(DW, [ShipDate])
ORDER BY 
    Day;
```

I get this result:

```
Day    Number of shipments/per day
------------------------------------
1      693
2      164
3      232
4      728
5      577
6      842
7      776
```

Comment: and what's the issue?

Comment: I need to convert the day(6) to Friday and "print" "we send most shipments on Fridays...

Comment: and you are saying you can't convert it to friday?

Comment: Yes, I can't convert it to Friday and print we send most shipments on Fridays

Comment: Read up on [SET DATEFIRST](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598(v=sql.105).aspx) and [DATENAME](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: i don't understand the requirement here.. please post the desired result.

Comment: The desired result is

Comment: The desired result is " we sent most shipments on Friday."

Comment: Finally we see the desired result - please edit your question and add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this using `derived table`, `case statement` and `concat` otherwise use other `concatenation method`

```
select 
concat ('We sent most shipments on ',
(case DD
  when 1 then 'Sunday'
  when 2 then 'Monday'
  when 3 then 'Tueday'
  when 4 then 'Wednesday'
  when 5 then 'Thursday'
  when 6 then 'Friday'
  else
    'Saturday'
  end
  )) result

 from
(
SELECT top 1 DATEPART(DW, [ShipDate]) AS 'DD', COUNT(*) cnt
FROM   [Purchasing].[PurchaseOrderHeader]
WHERE  [ShipDate] IS NOT NULL
Group by DATEPART(DW, [ShipDate])
order by cnt desc
) x
```

Comment: I get this message :Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near ')'

Comment: Try again... which sqlversion?

Comment: There's no syntax error. +1 for coding without data.

Comment: Maybe i need to enclose the case statement but looks good to me. Cheers

Comment: @CD33172, please mark the question as correct, and please understand the lesson here - if you explain what you want straight away. you'll arrive at an answer more quickly